# Zurb Foundation's Sticky changes element's size on scroll

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have an element in the side bar I want to make 'sticky', like in the example on the Zurb site [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sticky.html).

It works, however when I scroll down the sticky element shrinks in width (see screenshots below).

I cannot tell why this is. My code is as below:

```
<div class="columns medium-4 medium-push-8 sticky-container" data-sticky-container>
   <div class="sticky" data-sticky data-margin-top="0">
           <!---CONTENT--->
   </div>
</div>
```

There are no external styles influencing the element.

Here's a gif of the issue I am seeing:

[image]

Comment: Share more code or link to what the issue you face

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what happens when the element goes from a normal block level element (which will be as wide as the parent element) to `position: fixed;`. The element only becomes as big as the content inside of it without otherwise defined widths.

A simple fix is to assign `width: 100%;`. Or you can always put enough content in the div so that the content pushes it as wide as it is when it isn't affixed.

See my example for reference. This is with `width: 100%;` defined. Remove `width: 100%;` and uncomment the long paragraph to see the alternate fix.

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```css
body {
  height: 500vh;
}

.sticky {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/js/foundation.js"></script>

<div class="columns medium-4 medium-push-8 sticky-container" data-sticky-container>
   <div class="sticky" data-sticky data-margin-top="0">
     <p>asdf</p>
     <!--<p>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf </p>-->
   </div>
</div>
```